# Can the values Of MLEs be negative?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, pareto-distribution

I am working on the Pareto model. After applying Reduced log likelihood for ECM algorithm , the MLE values of one of the parameters is negative. Can this be accepted?

Comment: At the moment this question is rather unclear. Can you edit it to specify the model you are working on?

Comment: Only if a negative value is possible for the parameter -- from the information you have given so far it is unclear whether that is the case or not.

Comment: Is the parameter theoretically restricted to be non-negative?  If so, this should be imposed as a constraint in the maximization (for MLE(). If the maximization, whether closed form or numerical optimization, produces a solution which is negative, then it should be re-run as a constrained optimization problem.  Non-negativity constraints can be handled by many numerical optimizers. A closed form solution might be available If the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions which incorporate the constraints can be solved in closed form.

Answer (score 1):

In general, yes, a maximum likelihood estimate can be negative. For example, the maximum likelihood estimate of the mean of a normal distribution when the data is just the singleton vector (-1) is -1.